# Joined Tables Causing Interference

Tags: sql, join

I have a large but somewhat straightforward SQL query. Basically, users on my site develop reputations for different types of activities, such as writing reviews, leaving comments, and adding entries to our database. For the most part, these points are stored in the reputable_actions table, and I retrieve them by LEFT JOINing the reputable_actions table repeatedly. This feels sloppy, but it mostly work.

The problem I'm experiencing is with two of the reputations, "reviewer" and "community." Unlike the others, they aren't stored in the reputable_actions table. Instead, their values are derived from the votes table, which I access by first LEFT JOINing the comments table. For some reason, joining the comments table causes all my other reputations to increase exponentially. In one trial, the "archivist" reputation was suppose to be 25, but when I joined the comments, it ballooned to 10050.

I'm a novice with SQL and I've tried what I know (namely, applying GROUP BY clauses to users.id), but I haven' had any luck yet. Some guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT users.*,
  SUM(COALESCE(reviewers.value, 0)) as reviewer,
  SUM(COALESCE(communities.value,0)) as community,
  SUM(COALESCE(developers.value,0)) as developer,
  SUM(COALESCE(moderators.value,0)) as moderator,
  SUM(COALESCE(marketers.value,0)) as marketer,
  SUM(COALESCE(archivists.value,0)) as archivist,
  SUM(COALESCE(karmas.value,0)) as karma
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN comments AS impressions
  ON impressions.user_id = users.id
  AND impressions.type = 'impression'
LEFT JOIN comments AS replies
  ON replies.user_id = users.id
  AND replies.type = 'reply'
LEFT JOIN votes AS reviewers
  ON reviewers.voteable_type = 'impression'
  AND reviewers.voteable_id = impressions.id
LEFT JOIN votes AS communities
  ON communities.voteable_type = 'reply'
  AND communities.voteable_id = replies.id
LEFT JOIN reputable_actions AS developers
  ON developers.reputation_type = 'developer'
  AND developers.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN reputable_actions AS moderators
  ON moderators.reputation_type = 'moderator'
  AND moderators.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN reputable_actions AS marketers
  ON marketers.reputation_type = 'marketer'
  AND marketers.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN reputable_actions AS archivists
  ON archivists.reputation_type = 'archivist'
  AND archivists.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN reputable_actions AS karmas
  ON karmas.reputation_type = 'karma'
  AND karmas.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: I assume there's supposed to be a GROUP BY clause at the end?

Comment: Good catch. I've added the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to do two separate group bys, and combine the results. There's a trick to avoid joining multiple times, it may not by faster if you have many other voteable types, or reputation types.

```
Select
  u.*,
  Coalesce(r.developer, 0) as developer,
  Coalesce(r.moderator, 0) as moderator,
  Coalesce(r.marketer, 0) as marketer,
  Coalesce(r.archivist, 0) as archivist,
  Coalesce(r.karma, 0) as karma,
  Coalesce(v.impressions, 0) as impressions,
  Coalesce(v.replies, 0) as replies
From
  users u
    Left Outer Join (
    Select
      user_id,
      Sum(Case When reputation_type = 'developer' Then value Else 0 End) as developer,
      Sum(Case When reputation_type = 'moderator' Then value Else 0 End) as moderator,
      Sum(Case When reputation_type = 'marketer' Then value Else 0 End) as marketer,
      Sum(Case When reputation_type = 'archivist' Then value Else 0 End) as archivist,
      Sum(Case When reputation_type = 'karma' Then value Else 0 End) as karma
    From
      reputable_actions
    Group By
      user_id
  ) r On u.id = r.user_id
    Left Outer Join (
    Select
      c.user_id,
      Sum(Case When c.type = 'impression' Then v.value Else 0 End) as impressions,
      Sum(Case When c.type = 'reply' Then v.value Else 0 End) as replies
    From
      comments c
        inner join -- maybe left outer?
      votes v
        on v.voteable_type = c.type And v.voteable_id = c.id
    Group By
      user_id
  ) v On u.id = v.user_id
```

[Example (with no data)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d8b7/1). If your tables are structured differently to this, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the great example. It's a bit beyond me, but slowly I've been making sense of it. I continue to get a syntax error at the end of "Coalesce(v.replies 0) as replies," and I assume this is because v.replies isn't getting properly created. I've tried using both inner and left outer joins to no avail. I think the problem is in the final line, "v On u.id = v.user_id." Votes don't have the right user_id; comments do. Unfortunately, I can't just do c.user_id here because comments are out of scope. (Right?) Any suggestions for relaying that information? I tried including the ids in a select.

Comment: @timothythehuman It's because I missed the comma between v.replies and 0, fixed now

Comment: Egads, I should have been able to catch that myself. Thanks for the help, though. I ran this through a battery of tests, and everything's coming out right. This was a huge help, and it's shown me a couple of better approaches to writing queries. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There are *multiple* rows in `comments` and/or `votes` that match *one* row in the "rest" of the join. This "multiplies" the resulting rows and multiplies the results of *other* aggregate functions with it (as you already noted).

The simplest solution is to get the `SUM(reviewers.value)` and `SUM(communities.value)` in a separate query.

BTW, you'll experience the same problem if there is ever more than one `reputable_actions` row (of the same `reputation_type`) matching the same `users` row.